# No Post matches the given query.in django

Tags: python, django

am using django 2.0 and here is the problem
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/post-detail/
Raised by:  blog.views.post_detail
No Post matches the given query.

here is the blog/urls

```html
from django.urls import path,include
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/',views.post_list,name="post_list"),
    path('blog/post-detail/',views.post_detail,name="post_detail"),

]
```

and views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from.models import Post

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    object_list=Post.objects.all()
    context={
        'object_list': object_list,
    }
    return render(request,"blog.html",context)

def post_detail(request,slug=None):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    context={
       'post':post,
    }
    return render(request,"post_detail.html",context)
```

and the post_detail.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block seo_title %}{% endblock %}
{% block seo_description %}{% endblock %}
{% block Content %}
<article>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<img src="images/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
  <div class="post-content">

<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
<div>
{{post.created}}  Author {{Post.user}}
<hr/>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
</article>

{% endblock Content %}
```

CAN ANYONE HELP ON THIS THE ONLY PROBLEM I SEE  THAT  SLUG THING I MUST HAVE CONFUSED SOMEWHERE
blog.html

```html
<!-- Blog -->
<div class="blog">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

      <!-- Blog Post-->
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% if obj.status == 'Published' %}
      <article>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <img src="images/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
        <div class="post-content">

    <h2>{{obj.title}}</h2>
    <div>
    {{obj.created}}  Author {{obj.user}}
    <hr/>
    <p>{{obj.body}}</p>
    <a class="mtr-btn button-navy ripple" href= "{% url 'post_detail' slug= post.slug %}">Continue reading →</a><br>
    </div>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a slug parameter in your detail URL.

Comment: still gives page not found The current path, blog/post-detail/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

The view `post_detail(request,slug=None)` is to view details about a post. So your URL pattern is incorrect:

```
path('blog/post-detail/<slug:slug>',views.post_detail,name="post_detail"),
```

To call it in templates, the simpler and correct way to do is:

```
<a class="mtr-btn button-navy ripple" href= "{% url 'post_detail' obj.slug %}">Continue reading →</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I  have added that line and here is the error  page not found The current path, blog/post-detail/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: did you add `obj.slug` in URL?

Comment: Yes i adde it  for the part continue leading it works fine fine but trying to access this url  http://localhost:8000/blog/post-detail/             gives an error  The current path, blog/post-detail/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Yes i adde it  for the part continue leading it works fine fine but trying to access this url  http://localhost:8000/blog/post-detail/             gives an error  The current path, blog/post-detail/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: If you have changed your url pattern to `blog/post-detail/<slug:slug>`. the `localhost:8000/blog/post-detail ` will no longer a valid url. To see a post details, you need to add the slug of the post. so `localhost:8000/blog/post-detail/post-slug`

Answer (score 0):

```
#FOLLOW THIS PROCEDURE.I HOPE IT HELPS YOU OR ANY ONE ELSE IN THE FUTURE

# At blog/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import (post_list, post_detail)


urlspatterns = [
    path('blog/', post_list, name='post-list'),
    path('<str:slug>/blog/post-detail/', post_detail, name='post-detail'),
```

]

```
#At blog/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all() 
    template_name = blog/post_list.html
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

def post_detail(request, slug):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    template_name = blog/post_detail.html
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


# At the template/blog/post_list.html
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article>
            <div>      
                <small>{{ post.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                <h2><a href="{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p >{{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}


# At template/blog/post_detail.html
<article>
    <div>
        <small>{{ posts.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>     
        <h2>{{ posts.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ posts.body }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
#The above code should fix the the issue properly.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your a following Django 3 By Example Book can check this soltuion because I had the same problem.

1. Book teach how to create Post with a slug attribute with
   models.SlugField and unique_for_date='pusblish' condition.
2. Then you add some posts from admin site.
3. Then you add some posts from admin site but then in admin.py book teach how to edit the register with
   prepopulated_fields = {'sulg':('title',)}.
4. Finally, book teach you how to edit posts.

This is a problem because never
going to find a post created. So, the solution for me was delete
posts and the create new ones.

here my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.month,
                             self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('status', 'publish')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
# another views...
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]
```

**my_site/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```